# ArcMap View panel flashes constantly - rendering ArcMap unusable

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, shapefile, performance, mapview

While using ArcMap it will start to flash constantly in the layout view panel.  As well, if I zoom into the layout, it will work for a split second and then return to the original view scale on its own.  If I change to map view it will automatically zoom out to the max extent and continue to flash. My gaming computer is only 1 year old with an excellent graphics card.  This behavior only happens with ArcMap, no other programs have issues.  I have recorded this behavior.
Link below.
https://photos.app.goo.gl/JPKWvZh1Ws6W5tKH8

Comment: Did ArcMap behave like this earlier in the same machine? Did you ever try disconnecting the mouse and keyboard and check if the same happened?

Comment: Hi Yogesh, No ArcMap was fine a month ago.  I did unplug my mouse and re-started but it still does the same thing but doesn't blink as fast.  As well if I am working on a project for several hours then I lose the ability to shift/select multiple lines in the attribute tables. Sometimes if I try to select one line it appears selected but if click to show only this selected line in the table - nothing is selected. I have to close ArcMap and restart.  That will fix the shift/select issue for a short period of time but does not fix the blinking. This is seriously hampering my workdays.

Comment: Navigate to C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local and rename the ESRI folder, get a step back into C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Roaming and once again rename the ESRI folder here. Relaunch the application and test.